# How to fit a logarithmic line to multiple series in sgplot in SAS?

Tags: plot, sas

I have the current macro in sas

```
%macro Plot_Rolling_Avgs(id, ylabel_, xlabel_, title_, avg_1, avg_2, avg_3, avg_4, avg_5, avg_6);
proc Sgplot data=VA_PUR_Cur_Cur_Roll;  
SERIES X = &id Y = &avg_1;
SERIES X = &id Y = &avg_2;
SERIES X = &id Y = &avg_3;
SERIES X = &id Y = &avg_4;
SERIES X = &id Y = &avg_5;
SERIES X = &id Y = &avg_6;
YAXIS LABEL = &ylabel_;
XAXIS LABEL = &xlabel_; 
Title &title_;
keylegend / location=inside position=topleft across=1;

ods graphics on / 
    width=15.0in
    height=5.0in;
run;                                                                                                                                    
quit;      
%mend Plot_Rolling_Avgs;
```

Which gives me the result:
[image]

I'm trying to add logarithmic average lines to the graph for each of the time series. I'm trying to avoid create another column of logarithmic averages and plot those as well, and instead am hoping there's a built-in function to use.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS has, as of 9.4, two trendline options built in:

- REG, which fits a regression trend line based on a polynomial regression (can have beween 0 and 10 degrees, so 1=linear 2=quadratic etc.)
- LOESS, which fits a LOESS smooth curve (which is a locally-weighted regression)

See [the documentation for SGPLOT](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/67909/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0mn6vl6clqbgyn1ivs69lezdxhf.htm) for more information.  I don't believe there is anything that works across multiple series like you describe here, unfortunately.

You might be able to do something if you move from SGPLOT to the GTL (graph template language); there you can do some computations inside the graphing procedure itself.